# Why does loop doesnt stop at .showdialog in formloadevent

Tags: vb.net, loops, form-load

Hello here is a very strange bug I cannot solve. I have a while loop in my formload that   looks this way :

```
While loginOK = False And pstop = False
        LoginForm1.ShowDialog()
        If NewReg = True Then
            While RegErfolgreich = False
                Registrierung.ShowDialog()

                Dim con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.SLXADRIUMDEVConnectionString)
                con.Open()

                Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert Into sysdba.PL_Userverwaltung        (Benutzername, Passwort, [E-Mail-Adresse], Profil_OK) Values('" & RegBenutzername & "', '" & RegPassword & "', '" & RegEMailAdresse & "', 'f')", con)

                If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                    My.Settings.Benutzername = RegBenutzername
                    My.Settings.Passwort = RegPassword
                    My.Settings.Save()
                    Me.Close()
                    RegErfolgreich = True
                Else
                    MsgBox("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.")
                End If

            End While
        Else
            NewReg = False
        End If

    End While
```

The problem is that after closing loginform1 he jumps back in the loop, and when he starts looping again he opens loginform1 and closes it instantly. and loops again in the while loop.

That means I have a endless loop, which shows the loginform1 and closes it a millisecond later.
One thing to mention is that a friend of mine opened my project in an older vs studio version and this mysterious bug doesnt happen??

Hope for input cheers

EDIT:

Here is loginform1 code

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click

    If UsernameTextBox.Text <> "" And PasswordTextBox.Text <> "" Then
        Startseite.LoginUsername = UsernameTextBox.Text
        Startseite.LoginPassword = PasswordTextBox.Text
        Startseite.loginOK = True
        Me.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("Bitte Benutzername und Passwort eingeben!")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cancel.Click
    Startseite.pstop = True
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub LoginForm1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If My.Settings.Benutzername <> "" And My.Settings.Passwort <> "" Then
        'MsgBox(My.Settings.Benutzername & "  " & My.Settings.Passwort)
        UsernameTextBox.Text = My.Settings.Benutzername
        PasswordTextBox.Text = My.Settings.Passwort
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lblNeuRegistrieren_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblNeuRegistrieren.Click
    Startseite.NewReg = True
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: To answer your question, the code of LoginForm1 would be very interesting. In the code of the form, is there code that closes the form right away under certain circumstances? Also note that the line `NewReg = False` is meaningless as it is run only if `NewReg` is already false.

Comment: show edit :) no problem

Comment: The Load event is risky, on some Windows versions it has the habit of swallowing exceptions when a debugger is attached.  Look in the Output window for any "First chance exception" notifications.  Get the debugger to stop on them with Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

About your error, probably you didn't initialize your startseite variable to be your main form, loginOK And pstop never get changed and that's why the loop never stops. But on the rest of your code, some general tips.

This is unnecesary

```
    If NewReg = True Then
    ''
    Else
        NewReg = False
    End If
```

If NewReg is not true, then it's false by definition. Should be

```
    If NewReg Then
    ''
    End If
```

Also, overloading the showDialog on loginForm1 is a better solution than adding a yourmainclass object on the second form. It is easier to debug and provides better reusability.

Comment: startseite is my main form. the while loop is to make shure that you have registered and logged in bevore startseite pops up.

loginok changes when you click ok in loginform1, and you set the password and login right.

Comment: loginok does not change when you click ok in loginform1, which is why your loop keeps going on forever. You are doing myclass.value = true when you should be doing myobject.value=true. Using me.owner or me.parent(depending on framework) instead of startseite would probably do the trick since it actually points to the object.

Comment: Thx Hamster I got it working on. After hours of trying out :))

Answer (score 0):

try exiting loop on message box

```
If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
    My.Settings.Benutzername = RegBenutzername
    My.Settings.Passwort = RegPassword
    My.Settings.Save()
    Me.Close()
    RegErfolgreich = True
Else
    MsgBox("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.")
    Exit While
End If
```